# What is the difference between scope_identity() and current_identity()?

Tags: sql-server

```
What is the difference between scope_identity() and current_identity()?
```

Scope_identity and current _identity both are similar and it will return the last identity     value generated in the table.
  Scope_Identity will return the identity value in table that is currently in scope

is it correct definition for this question?

Comment: There is nothing like `current_identity()` i think you mean `IDENT_CURRENT()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IDENT_CURRENT is similar to the SQL Server 2000 identity functions SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY. All three functions return last-generated identity values.
>
> However, the scope and session on which last is defined in each of these functions differ:
>
> - IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.
> - @@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.
> - SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

@@IDENTITY

It returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

Let me explain this... suppose we create an insert trigger on table which inserts a row in another table with generate an identity column, then @@IDENTITY returns that identity record which is created by trigger.
SCOPE_IDENTITY

It returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.

Let me explain this... suppose we create an insert trigger on table which inserts a row in another table with generate an identity column, then SCOPE_IDENTITY result is not affected but if a trigger or a user defined function is affected on the same table that produced the value returns that identity record then SCOPE_IDENTITY returns that identity record which is created by trigger or a user defined function.
IDENT_CURRENT

It returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

In other words, we can say it is not affected by scope and session, it only depends on a particular table and returns that table related identity value which is generated in any session or scope.

find **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE_IDENTITY-IDENT_C)**